# Unable to mount 2 volumeMounts into nginx container in kubernetese, container start but nginx no

Tags: kubernetes, containers, persistent-volume-claims, mounted-volumes

I'm trying to mount 2 volumeMounts in the same container in kubernates but it seems that with volume 2 the nginx service does not start

This is the yaml I use

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: nginx
spec:
containers:
- name: myfrontend
image: nginx
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: "/var/www/html"
name: mypd
- mountPath: "/etc/nginx/conf.d"
name: mypd
volumes:
- name: mypd
persistentVolumeClaim:
claimName: nginx-pvc

```
pv and pvc are already present without problems.
If deploy the above manifest the pod start but if, inside the pod, execute a netstat -ntlp the result is this

root@nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
root@nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d#





If deploy the same manifest but wiht only one volumeMounts al works fine

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
        name: mypd
  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nginx-pvc`

root@nginx:/# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro

Do I have to create a PVC for each volumeMounts?

Thanks in advance to everyone
```

Comment: A volume mount here doesn't seem like it's the right approach.  How does content get into the `nginx-pvc` persistent volume?  Would it be more maintainable to build a custom image that contains the assets you need to serve, and delete this volume mount entirely?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I would need, I am still inexperienced in this field, to upload custom sites to nginx, so I need to upload the necessary files from the kubernates master to the shared share that is mapped to nginx.
At the moment I was thinking of mounting /etc/nginx/conf.d to load the configuration files of the various hosts files, and /usr/share/nginx/html to load the website files.
Did I take the wrong approach?
Thank you

Comment: On at least the systems I've worked with, you can't log into the Kubernetes master, and copying files directly in and out of Kubernetes volumes is tricky.

Comment: Ok...what's is the best method to deploy and nginx as web server with various sites and virtual host? When add a new site for customer I need to load the files and add the configuration

Comment: For Nginx itself, consider whether an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) setup can meet your needs.  You'd need to deploy other server Deployments to serve the actual contents, or serve static files from somewhere outside the cluster.